# Deploying React App To Github Pages Yields Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am trying to host my react application in Github Pages.

I've done the same thing with a Vue based project, and had no issues, but with React, things are different.

I have gone over the following tutorials:

- [Tutorial #1](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-host-your-react-app-on-github-pages-for-free-919ad201a4cb)
- [Tutorial #2](https://medium.com/mobile-web-dev/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages-in-less-than-5-minutes-d6c4ffd30f14)

I am able to deploy the application to Github Pages, but am seeing the following error:

> Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

[image: Error]

Yes, my manifest is found inside my public folder and I do not know where the problem originates from.
I've tried reading various SO questions relating to this subject, but haven't found anything that is relevant.

I also tried creating a vanilla react project and following the tutorials, but got the same issues.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Random App Name",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/TomerPacific/projectName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

What is happening here? Is the problem a configuration issue?

Comment: What is does the url for your app look like? Lol, and I don't think you are using the "homepage" field the way you are supposed to.

Comment: In general, if your app is at "https://my-username.github.io/", the default React build settings (without "homepage" in "package.json") should work along with setting the GitHub page to serve from the root folder. Have you been through https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths?

Comment: @KibongeMurphy - I changed the app name and the homepage in the package.json just for this question so as to not give it away. The values there are not the real values. Also, if you look at the tutorial links I shared, both of them specify to add the homepage key.

Comment: Yes sure. I figured as much. But it is important that it has the right form though. I host my portfolio at "username.github.io". I have this other repo for a home automation project that is hosted at "username.github.io/home-remote". The "username" should be your GitHub username. Also, you should go into the developer tools, then the network tab, and look at the exact URLs that generate the 401 errors. It is most likely the case that the URLs point to the wrong places. If you could add a screenshot of that to the question, it would help to assist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Kibonge Murphy's suggestion, I checked the request url for all the network requests being made and found out that it was wrong.

Instead of having the URL of the Github page as the homepage key in the package.json file, I put in the URL of the repository.

Meaning,

I should have put this : `https://tomerpacific.github.io/projectName/`

Instead of `https://github.com/TomerPacific/projectName`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was caused by the fact that the server sent a 404 error page instead of the manifest. In the sources tab of Chrome dev tools click on the file that is your manifest and confirm it's not a error page.